# iOS - Caching Images and Managing Storage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, caching

My iOS app is somewhat similar to Facebook in the sense that it will display user generated 'posts' in a scrollable tableview, each with an image to display.

To try and avoid downloading images each time the users scrolls through the tableview, I'm using [FTWCache](https://github.com/FTW/FTWCache) to store each post's image data, as such:

```
[FTWCache setObject:loadedData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"postID%@", post.ID]];
```

Is this a poor practice, to lean heavily on a caching class like this? After awhile, the cache would become considerable in size, should I be flushing it every so often?

If anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `FTWCache` but I can see that it was last maintained 3 years ago while `SDWebImage` or `AFNetworking` is maintained daily with a really big community behind it.

I'd go with `AFNetworking`. You shouldn't worry too much about leaning heavily on caching. That's what it's for. You could however read a bit more about how `NSURLCache` works and how `AFNetworking` is using it.

Here's the gist of it:

> AFNetworking takes advantage of the caching functionality already
>   provided by NSURLCache and any of its subclasses. So long as your
>   NSURLRequest objects have the correct cache policy, and your server
>   response contains a valid Cache-Control header, responses will be
>   automatically cached for subsequent requests.